# Enable GRANT options for users

Tags: mysql

Create username and password for the user and give grant to that user for insert , update, select to that user.

I am logged as admin and create user

Syntax :

```
CREATE USER 'demoone'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

but it displays some error message in MySQL database

In my web host i am creating a database and also read only username.
I am giving different passwords and different usernames for that database.

but when i am trying to login then both times it displays same options(like updata,delete...etc...).

I an giving GRANT to one user then mysql displays error message.
Syntax: 
     GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';

I don't know what is wrong.
Please rectify me.
Thanks.

Comment: When you login do you login as a superadmin with grant priveleges?

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

means , You are giving select and insert permission to the user 'someuser' from 'somehost' machine on *.*(means all tables in all databases).

Please be mind to flush the privileges.